# Flutter Dismissible causing unnecesary redraw when pushed navigated on top

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm making an app with Flutter, and I found a weird behaviour that I got to reproduce in a small demo: https://pastebin.com/ZJd2fnHK

The objective is to have a TextField that when in focus should select the whole text. I achieved this with a FocusNode.

Everything was working fine, until I set a Dismissible widget to remove items from a list. For some reason (probably drawing ones) the whole page has a rebuild and the focusnode state is lost.

It's very interesting since the issue only happens when the widget is within a page that has being pushed by the navigator. The same Widget works fine in the root Page.

The Widget is the following:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    textControllerA.text = "Hello";
    textControllerB.text = "World";
    return Column(children: [
      Dismissible(
        key: Key("potatoes"),
        onDismissed: (direction) {},
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              child: TextField(
                focusNode: focusNodeA,
                controller: textControllerA,
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        child: TextField(
          focusNode: focusNodeB,
          controller: textControllerB,
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      ),
    ]);
  }
```

Maybe I should try to store the focus' state in state, but that'd have some overhead. Or maybe (possibly) I'm doing something very wrong, in which case I would love to have some guidance.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

You should use **StatefulWidget** and call **setState**

```
 onDismissed: (direccion) {
      setState(() {
          ...
      });
```

Comment: Answer has nothing to do with the problem I originally posted.
Just calling setState has no relation with this.